# Invalid Excel Binding object

Tags: office-js

What is the proper way to delete an invalid binding in ExcelJS?

If a binding exists on a Excel table and the table is deleted the binding becomes invalid. One can load the bindings again (on a button click for example) and the invalid binding will be loaded:

context.workbook.bindings.load('id');
...

However, any attempt to do anything with the binding (delete it) causes an InvalidBinding exception. There appears to be no way to tell if a binding is valid or not (it only has id and type properties).

So the question is, once an invalid binding occurs how does one get rid of it so that subsequent loads of the bindings only load valid one's?

Cheers,

Dave

Comment: Have you tried `Bindings.releaseByIdAsync({id})`?

Comment: Hi Marc. I'm having trouble determining if the binding is bad. How does one figure out if a binding is no longer good so that it can be released?

Comment: You'll need to catch the `InvalidBinding` and then execute `Bindings.releaseByIdAsync({id})` within the exception handler.

Comment: Dave, thanks for bringing this up.  Let me pass this on to the team.  To Marc's recommendation, while it might work, you will find it quite painful/awkward to combine the "Office 2016" syntax (which is what you're using) and the Office 2013 syntax (methods ending in "Async").  I can ask around and see if there is a way to retrieve and act on this information while staying in the Excel host-specific (2016) syntax.

Comment: I believe that this is a bug, and that one of my colleagues has identified the issue.  We should have more info soon...

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft Any update on this? I didn't see anything directly relevant in the github issue list. Appears that the above (checking validity via catching exception, deleting via 2013 syntax) is still the only option here.

Comment: @Wiseguy, I'm no longer involved in the day-to-day work of Excel APIs.  If there is still an issue, I'd recommend filing a bug on https://github.com/officedev/office-js/issues

Comment: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/804 has been opened for this.

Comment: Based on our team's investigation, and confirmed with the PM of this feature, the way to address this issue should be a new feature for the binding object, created 3747318 workitem to track this feature request. So would you please provide us feedback via https://officespdev.uservoice.com/. and upvote for this feature. thanks for your support.

Comment: @RaymondLu - Where, specifically? Searching on "binding" there doesn't seem to turn up this feature request.