# Getting rid of invalid bindings in a workbook

Tags: office-js, office-addins

If I create a binding for a range in a worksheet, then delete the worksheet (but not the entire workbook), the binding is no longer valid. Trying to do almost anything with it raises this error:

> This object binding is no longer valid due to previous updates.

How do I remove those bindings? Calling `delete` on them just raises the error above:

```js
return Excel.run(async context => {
    const binding = /*...get a binding from context.workbook.bindings...*/;
    // Try to use it
    try {
        binding.load("id");
        await context.sync(); // Fails with the error above
    } catch {
        binding.delete();
        await context.sync(); // Fails with the same error
    }
});
```

...and the binding remains in the workbook. The problem with that is it gets in the way of iterating bindings; having to `context.sync` for each individual binding is slow, but if I don't and there are invalid ones, the error occurs and I can't do a batch of them.

How can I get rid of invalid bindings?

**Note:** I don't know the `id` of the binding in advance, so I can't even use the older API method (`Bindings.releaseByIdAsync({id})`) mentioned in the comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45586251/invalid-excel-binding-object).

Related github issue: [*Difficulty working with invalid bindings*](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/804)

Comment: It looks like all the overloads of the [BindingCollection.add()](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/excel/excel.bindingcollection?view=excel-js-preview#add-range--bindingtype--id-) methods require an `id` parameter. So could you record the binding IDs in a global variable just before you create the binging? Also, would the [BindingCollection.gtItemOrNullObject()](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/excel/excel.bindingcollection?view=excel-js-preview#getitemornullobject-id-) method be helpful?

Comment: @RickKirkham - Thanks. Our add-in has to discover the bindings, we don't know the IDs in advance. (We know the general format of them, but not the specific IDs.) Also, oddly, invalid bindings don't appear to be null objects. o_O Fortunately, I've found a way around which I just posted.

Comment: @RickKirkhami - That is to say, it has to discover them in a workbook created previously, so we don't have any global information lying around. (Indeed, the bindings themselves are the workbook-global information we need. We just wish they were work*sheet*-specific, but that's coming...later...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that even though `context.sync()` throws the "invalid binding" error when all you've done is load the binding's `id` (as in the question), it **does** populate the `id` properties of the bindings you've queued up (even ones after an invalid binding in the list). Which means you can use the older API mentioned in comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45586251/invalid-excel-binding-object) to remove it, because you have the ID.

This code will load the IDs of bindings, and if at least one binding is invalid, will work through them removing all the invalid ones:

```js
const { bindings } = context.workbook;
bindings.load("items");
await context.sync();
for (const binding of bindings.items) {
    binding.load("id");
}
try {
    await context.sync();
} catch (e) {
    if (e.code === "InvalidBinding") {
        for (const binding of bindings.items) {
            const { id } = binding; // Works, surprisingly
            try {
                binding.load("isNullObject");
                await context.sync();
            } catch {
                // This is an invalid binding
                await releaseById(id); // For me, this never fails
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That uses this helper function that wraps the old API:

```
function releaseById(id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Use the old API to remove it
        Office.context.document.bindings.releaseByIdAsync(id, result => {
            if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                resolve(result.value);
            } else {
                reject(result.error);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question.

This is a new feature for the binding object, we have 3747318 work item to track this feature request. if the solution doesnt work well, I would suggest you also vote for this feature request on UserVoice at https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/40468168-make-working-with-invalid-bindings-easier.

Thanks